# why do we use " realizes" instead of "realized" in this sentence

Tags: grammaticality

> Finally, he realizes that people have gossiped about their affair and that he has brought her dishonor.

I saw this sentence in Cambridge dictionary.However, I think it should be "realized" because the action of" realize" is in the past. 
could you help me? thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that follows the realisation in the sentence is in present tense. *That people have gossiped* and *that he has brought her dishonour*, both the sentences have 'Have' and 'Has' as verbs instead of 'had'.

The core idea of this sentence is that the person is coming to be aware of something in real time, at present. Like -

*I realize that I am wrong.* or *I realize it now that you don't want to live with the family.* or *He doesn't realize what he is doing to the country.*

If you were to construct your sentence differently, you could write -

*Finally, he realized that people had gossiped about their affair and that he had brought her dishonor.*

This would be the correct way of writing it in the past tense. Also, as mentioned by Peter, it is also a style of writing that authors use. Instead of narrating a story in past tense they chose to do it in present many a times.

Answer (score 0):

The technique the author is using is called "***time shift***" where the character is described at some time in the past.  It is used for stylistic effect.  The author could also have used "***realized***" without loss of meaning.

Comment: thank you Peter. so now i know one more usage of the simple present tense.